# Python3 initializing 2D Array ignores index specification range(start,end,step)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I want to initialize an array in python3 with an index NOT starting at zero and 2 dimensions.

```
x_length=16
y_length=4
x_start=-4
y_start=-400
# Later passing those variables with:
level_matrix=generate_area(x_length,y_length,x_start,y_start)
```

Part of the function:

```
def generate_area(xlen,ylen,xstart,ystart):
  matrix=[[0 for y in range(ystart, ystart+ylen)] for x in range(xstart, xstart+xlen)]
  for index, value in enumerate(matrix):
    print(f"S1_vec('{index}')<= {value}")
  for index, value in enumerate(matrix[0]):
    print(f"S1_vec('{index}')<= {value}")

  for x in range(xstart, xstart+xlen):
    for y in range(ystart, ystart+ylen):
      print("Y:"+str(y))
      print("X:"+str(x))
```

Output:

```
S1_vec('0')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('1')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('2')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('3')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('4')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('5')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('6')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('7')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('8')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('9')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('10')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('11')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('12')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('13')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('14')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('15')<= [0, 0, 0, 0]
S1_vec('0')<= 0
S1_vec('1')<= 0
S1_vec('2')<= 0
S1_vec('3')<= 0
Y:-400
X:-4


IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Well, as you can clearly see, there is no negative indexes in the array. This also does not properly work with positive offset as well. The loops want to access offset index values and the script obviously fails, since the index only gets created from 0 to the var1 in case of in `range(var1, var2)`. This makes no sense, since it should work like: `range(starting_point, end_point, steps_if_needed)`. And the copy paste for loop syntax gets successfully used later in the script in multiple instances.

What causes such weird behavior and how to fix this without changing anything else except the initialization of the array in the code? I need 2D arrays to exactly work within the specified region. Is there a simple solution?

Edit:

Just to clarify the goal:

I need a 2D array with negative index capabilities. The range is known, but each entry needs to be defined. Append is useless, because it will not add a specific negative index for me.

If I for example need to define matrix[-4][-120]="Jeff", this needs to work. I do not even care at all, if there is a solution like in Bash, where you have to write matrix["-4,-120"]. Yet I need a reasonable way to address such entries.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: An array with negative indexes. With the 4 variables specified in the range of array[-4][-400] to array[16][4]. Basically a table with negative x and y index. Like coordinates in a game. Why should that not work? Works even in bash (*.sh) scripts. "Any" language can do that, I would think and expect.

Comment: please edit your question to contain your desired output.

Comment: Does Python not support a way to address a negative index for an array? No one will programm a game in python for sure. But what, if I need to work with negative indexes? That is the goal. Any other way to achieve that? I want to generate a 2D Noise map and save it as an array for further processing.

Comment: in python, negative indices are indices  that count from the end. E.g. a[-1] gives the last element of an array. As for "nobody will program a game in python", check out [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a virtual indexing strategy to do the same. Here is my approach:

```
offset = 5
size = 4
a = [x for x in range(offset,offset+size)]

print(a) # [5, 6, 7, 8]

def get_loc(idx):
    return a[idx-offset]

def set_loc(idx, val):
    a[idx-offset] = val
    

set_loc(6,15)
print(a) # [5, 15, 7, 8]

set_loc(8, 112)
print(a) # [5, 15, 7, 112]
```

This code was just to understand the what i mean by virtual indexing strategy, you can simply use below to get and set values:

```
# to get a[n] use a[n-offset]
print(a[8-offset]) # 112

# to set a[n] = x | Use a[n-offset] = x
a[7-offset] = 21
print(a) # [5, 15, 21, 112]
```

Comment: @HeartOfGermany, Does this help? Are you trying anything else?